# Algorithm for timers for hiding and showing a form

Tags: timer

Hi I'm currently making a subliminal messaging program in windows forms and I have a form that appears then quickly disappears.

I now have pretty much everything working except for the timings for my timers that will show and then hide the form.

I'm currently using 2 timers

1. The timer for showering is at 1000 intervals
2. The timer for hiding is at 750 intervals.

Now I know this isn't a good choice as the timings will keep changing between how long it takes for a form to be hidden once it has been made to appear.

I can't figure out an algorithm that will make the intervals work together in a way so the revealing of a form then hiding doesn't change but is still done quickly.

I'm needing the form to be hidden very quickly once it appears but to not be shown again for around  3-5 seconds.

Thanks

Comment: How are you defining intervals here? how does it convert to seconds? also, if you want to have your form open for the same amount of time each time, can't you just have the two timers on the same interval but staggered?

Comment: I'm using two interval timers on the form with one that hides the form and another that then brings it back up. The intervals are at ticks I think, im not really sure how the timers work I just drag and dropped them on windows form. And set the intervals on the properties

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to chain your timers, starting and stopping them so they retain their interval.

You say you want the form to show after 3-5 seconds and then hide after 750ms (the timer intervals are documented as milliseconds).

If we call the timers Timer_Show and Timer_Hide and the form instance as SubForm then we can have:

```
public partial class SubForm : Form
{
    public SubForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // This timer will show the screen
        Timer Timer_Show = new Timer();
        Timer_Show.Tick += Timer_Show_Tick;
        Timer_Show.Interval = 3000;
        Timer_Show.Enabled = true;

        // This timer will hide the screen
        Timer Timer_Hide = new Timer();
        Timer_Hide.Tick += Timer_Hide_Tick;
        Timer_Hide.Interval = 750;
        Timer_Hide.Enabled = false;
    }

    public void Timer_Show_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer_Show.Stop();
        this.Show();
        Timer_Hide.Start();
    }

    public void Timer_Hide_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer_Hide.Stop();
        this.Hide();
        Timer_Show.Start();
    }
}
```

I've moved the Timer instantiations to the constructor so you can see what's going on.

First we set the `Timer_Show` interval to 3000ms (3 seconds). Then we set the `Timer_Hide` interval to 750ms. We disable `Timer_Hide` but enable `Timer_Show`.

After 3 seconds, `Timer_Show_Tick` will fire. This will then disable `Timer_Show`, show the current instance of `SubForm` and then start `Timer_Hide`.

Then after 750ms `Timer_Hide_Tick` fires, stops `Timer_Hide`, hides the current instance of `SubForm` then starts `Timer_Start` to restart the whole process.

The screen will always show 3 seconds after it was last shown and will remain visible for 750ms. This will keep your show/hide timers in sync.

If you want to change the 3 seconds to something else then you can instantiate a `Random`. E.G.

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

Have `Random` as a class level variable and then in `Timer_Hide_Tick` just before you call `Timer_Show.Start()` you can call `Timer_Show.Interval = rand.NewRand(3000, 5000);` which will select a random number between 3000 and 5000 for the interval value so showing the screen won't always be 3 seconds after it was last shown.

Your screen show/hide will still retain their syncronization so you'll never get into the situation where hide fires while the screen is already hidden.